# Is it still galut even though a lot of Jews are in Israel

Tags: beis-hamikdash, messiah, chasidut-hasidism, chabad, yerushalayim-jerusalem

BH

Is it still galut even though correct me if I’m wrong most Jews are in Israel? If yes what’s the meaning of Geulah?

Comment: First ask what do you mean by "galut"

Comment: Worth a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_population_by_country  .  People with Jewish connections in the US are almost twice the Jewish population of Israel.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi that's not the same as people who are halachically Jewish, and it separates out "West Bank", when that is usually halachically treated as part of Israel.  It probably still isn't quite a majority in Israel though.

Comment: what do you mean by "it" is?

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in Shabbos 21a says:

> The only difference between this world and the messianic era is subjugation of the exiles to other kingdoms, from which the Jewish people will be released.

The Satmar Rebbe wanted very much to live in Eretz Yisrael, but he left because he wanted to give tzedakah and raise money, and he could not do that in the State. So, "what defines exile"?

According to Chassidic thought, galus, e.g. exile, is defined as "the absence of the presence of G-d", as the verse in Devarim (31:18) says: "I will hide My face". See also [this article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2321750/jewish/Introduction.htm#footnote1a2321750).

You ask if it is still exile if the majority of the Jewish people are living in the land of Israel. Well, the Satmar Rebbe, in his magnus opus "Vayoel Moshe" (Siman 14), explains to us [that](https://www.truetorahjews.org/images/vayoelmosheenglish.pdf):

> There is nothing wrong with a small portion of the Jewish people living in Eretz Yisroel. As long as the majority of the Jewish people is in the land of their enemies, bearing the decree of exile, Hashem's promise to protect the entire Jewish people from destruction - even those living in Eretz Yisroel - is in effect. The Ramban only means that there will be danger if the majority of the Jewish people ascend as a wall against the will of Hashem, who made the decree of exile. So it comes out the fact that most of the Jewish people lives in exile, in accordance with Hashem's decree, is what saves even the Jews of Eretz Yisroel.

So, if the Jews are living in the land of Israel, is the exile over? There is a famous story of the Chazon Ish, Rabbi Avraham Yishaya Karelitz (1878-1953).

Reb Tzvi Dov Abraham, rav of Kedushas Levi in Monsey was once sitting in a room with the Chazon Ish when suddenly a man came into the room. The man was full of joy and spoke with great enthousiasm about the State of Israel. "We see with our own eyes that this is the beginning of the redemption) [e.g. that the Jews are now massively living in the Land of Israel]. To this, the Chazon Ish told "Bring me a Gemara of Kesubos", he did, and the Chazon Ish looked up Kesubos 111a. The Chazon Ish hold his finger upon [the words of the Gemara (the three oaths and their punishment for violation them)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.111a.7), and told this person:

> Es shteit az men vet azoy ton vet azoy kumen, men hot azoy geton un es iz azoy gekumen, un ir zogt az es iz aschalta degeulah!” (It says that if we do this, this will happen. They did it, and it happened. And you say it’s the beginning of the redemption!) (Mishkenos HaRo"im, p. 1195)

[image]

[ליקוט דברי החזון איש זצ"ל p. 3](https://www.truetorahjews.org/images/chazonish.pdf)

So, is it still considered galus if we live in the State of Israel? Yes.

Rav Moshe Shternbuch actually cited the same Gemara I cited at the beginning of this answer (Teshuvos VeHanhagos). He wrote, in the name of the Brisker Rav that, a) we have no Jewish king appointed to us [that rules according to halacha], b) there was no official, halachic kibbutz galiyot- e.g. gathering of the people, since Moshiach did not do that yet.

So, even if we are living in the State of Israel, this does by no means mean that the exile is over.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, added them in.

Comment: Thanks Shmuel. I am sure I am just being thick headed, but I still don't quite get the point the Chazon Ish is making.

Comment: I think the Chazon Ish meant that "it says if they do this, this happens" refers to all the problems over the past generations. "They did, it happened"- problems increased - so they think it is the beginning of redemption.